How to loop/get multiple data using BeanIO in XML file - Java Maven
I'm struggling with getting multiple data with XML files using BeanIO in Java. Im working with maven.
Sample File:
<orders>
    <order>
        <orderHeader>
            <orderId>123</orderId>
            <customerName>John Doe</customerName>
        </orderHeader>
        <orderItems>
            <item>
                <productId>ABC</productId>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <productId>XYZ</productId>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </orderItems>
         <orderItems>
            <item>
                <productId>ABC</productId>
                <quantity>2</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <productId>XYZ</productId>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
            <item>
                <productId>XYZ</productId>
                <quantity>1</quantity>
            </item>
        </orderItems>
    </order>
    <order>
        <orderHeader>
            <orderId>456</orderId>
            <customerName>Jane Smith</customerName>
        </orderHeader>
        <orderItems>
            <item>
                <productId>DEF</productId>
                <quantity>3</quantity>
            </item>
        </orderItems>
    </order>
</orders>


Imagine we have a file like this and need to get each 'order' data, 'orderHeader' data inside relevant 'order', get all multiple 'orderItems' and get all 'item' inside that each 'orderItem'.
I tried to create XML mapping and proceed with it. But getting lots of errors while trying to loop/get multiple data.

Take a look at the repeating segments documentation
